# How to solve Error message in Google Sheet array formula: The resulting array was too large

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I tried to use this formula below on my Google Sheet for around 10,000 row data:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(L3:L),M3:M&" - "&MMULT((M3:M=TRANSPOSE(M3:M))*(ROW(M3:M)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(M3:M))),SIGN(ROW(M3:M)))+0,IFERROR(1/0)))
```

but it came out error message.

"The resulting array was too large"

Can please advice me good solution?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to try, because is the simplest action, is to remove the blank rows below your data. Another simple option is to replace the open-ended references (L3:L, M3:M) by closed-end references i.e. L3:L10, M3:M10. You also might use functions like ARRAY_CONSTRAIN, FILTER, QUERY to limit the size for the values returned by the open-ended references.

Related

- [Remove empty rows in Google Spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/47284/88163)

Comment: @Mr.Liew You are welcome. Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Mr.Liew if want to ask for clarification instead of editing the question post a comment but if you want to ask a follow-up question please do that by posting a new question.